# Providing Bash substitution as a function argument

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

I have a following loop that works well:

```
function uppercase_all_letters() {
  for filename in *;
    do echo "${filename^^}";
  done;
}
```

How do I provide `"${filename^^}"` as a parameter to the function?

I tried it the usual well (`SUBSTITUTION="${filename^^}"`) but then Bash reports:

```
./test.sh: line 26: ${filename^^}: bad substitution
```

Comment: You are obviously not running the code with `bash`, but possibly with `dash` (`/bin/sh` on some Linuxes) or `zsh`, although `dash` would have said `Bad substitution` (upper case `B`) and would also have complained about the non-standard function definition.

Comment: @Kusalananda Only `bash` is using that error format; eg. `echo '${foo&&}' | bash` => `bash: line 1: ${foo&&}: bad substitution`. The OP is probably using some older version of bash which didn't support yet that syntax.

Comment: Could you please mention the version of `bash` that you use? The `^^` thing was added in `bash-4.0-alpha`.

Comment: @mosvy I think I misunderstood what the user wanted.  It would have made more sense if the code that uses `$SUBSTITUTION` (and which is what probably causes the error) was shown.

Comment: Yes, but who's printing that error? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it literally, you'd probably have to resort to eval:

```
function subst_all_filenames() {
    subst="$1"
    for filename in *
    do
        eval 'echo ${filename'"$subst"'}'
    done
}

subst_all_filenames "^^"
subst_all_filenames ",,"
subst_all_filenames ""
```

Alternatively, support only a known list of substitutions:

```
function subst_all_filenames() {
    case "$1" in
      ^^) for filename in *; do echo "${filename^^}"; done ;;
      ,,) for filename in *; do echo "${filename,,}"; done ;;
       *) printf "%s\n" * ;;
    esac
}
```

Sometimes such a helper function also isn't even necessary in the first place. It's quite normal to have such loops all over the place in a shell script.